# How to make web application to always start from give page

Tags: java, javascript, client, zk

In my context :

```
Context
 |
 |->  Login.zul
 |->  Home.zul
 |->  page1.zul
 |->  page2.zul
```

If I hit link to Home.zul I want it to redirect to Login if not authenticated, similarly for all the zul's if authentication is not done I would redirect it to Login screen

My Solution :
Do an authentication check in every Controller,if it is not authenticated redirect to Login.zul.

but I have many zul's and many controllers I donnot want to go in each controllers and do the same thing can some one think of any idea to it with out going to each class and make changes. May be in web.xml or zk.xml any tag can be added which I don't know to obtain the same result or do some client side scripting to get same result.Any thing clever that can reduce efforts.

Comment: You should have your main desktop page in the main webapp; but any included files you should hide undre /WEB-INF and include them from there for additional security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a [request interceptor](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Internationalization/Locale#The_Request_Interceptor).

Related to your comment, it looks like there are: [DesktopInit](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/DesktopInit.html), and [SessionInit](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/SessionInit.html) classes which you might be able to use. However, unless a user's session lasts indefinitely, without a request interceptor I am not sure that you would be able to handle session timeouts (unless you explicitly checked to ensure the user had a valid session everywhere it was accessed). This is also a security concern.

Comment: request interceptor will intercept every request to my application, which may raise synchronization issues, I need only method that will be called on Desktop initialization or Session initialization.

Comment: I assume the users session would not be indefinite. How would you accommodate session timeouts?

Comment: Really you should look to security your app using the container or framework code. If someone is trying to hack your site then you really do want every single request checked. So you should use an "out of zk" security mechanism on every serious site which enforces a login if it detects that someone is trying to access a resource when not logged in using 'normal' approach.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `Filters`
Filters are to be written once and configured in `web.xml`.
You can set filter for all resources or selected resources in your web app.
Filters can intercept each request for a resource. Using filters you can authenticate a user by inspecting the `cookie` sent by browser also you can modify the `request` and `response` content using it.
Helpful link : 
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-2001/jw-0622-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Java Web Application? If so you can configure that in your web-inf/web.xml file.

You can also create a Servlet Filter, to check for the Logged in status of the user before the request arrives at any Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for this purpose.